# VueJs Runtime components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS with my current project and when I tried to register new component and use it like `<component></component>` i got that runtime error. I found solution to render components like this:

```
import App from './components/Example.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

And yes It works, it really renders my component but is there any way to stick with that method of registering components ?

I've read about script to add in webpack but I'm not really sure what and where to do this is my script for running code: (watching for changes too)

```
watchify src/app.js -t vueify -t babelify -p browserify-hmr -p [ vueify/plugins/extract-css -o public/styles.bundle.css ] -o public/app.bundle.js
```

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. In order to use .vue files you need vue-loader, for example use a predefined setup of vue-cli: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Comment: @wostex When I use .vue files "standard" way I get runtime error, when I use them like I stated above it works fine.

Comment: I want to use `Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can use the component in your template the way you want. First, you can register the component globally.

```
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent.vue"

Vue.component("some-component", SomeComponent)
```

You could then use this in a template as `<some-component></some-component>`.

Second, you can locally register components.

```
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent.vue"

new Vue({
    components:{
        SomeComponent
    }
})
```

Which, again, you could use in the template as `<some-component></some-component>`, but only in the root Vue. If you wanted to use it in other components you would need to import it and add it to the local components of the component you want to use it in.